# Jmeter grpc test trying to find *grpc class when proto jar files has no class ending with grpc

Tags: performance, kotlin, testing, jmeter, grpc

I have updated the classpath in jmeter when testing grpc api, have also tested by providing the jar files in lib and lib>ext folder. However I keep running into the issue: ClassNotFoundException error being thrown for the ***APIGrpc class, which is being called in the initGrpcClient method of the GrpcClientSampler. This error is causing a NullPointerException in the sample method of the GrpcClientSampler, which is being caught by JMeter and reported in the log.
My proto file is ending with name *API. Not sure what is missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have added the grpc-api library to the lib/ext directory - But, it might require some transitive dependencies as well

By taking a look at the grpc-api library the below are the transitive dependencies - you should try adding them and give it a try

[image]